# Aggregated query results showing 'Null'

Tags: sql-server, null, sum, aggregate

I'm having a problem with a query in SQL Express 2016.
I've got print tracking data in a single table which shows the:

1. Device Serial Number (DeviceModel)
2. Department Cost Code (UserCostCode)
3. User Name (UserLogon)
4. Job Print Time (StartDateTime)
5. Page Count (TrackingPageCount)
6. If the print was colour (JobIsColour)
7. If the print was duplex (JobIsDuplex)
8. Associated cost of job (Price)

Now, I'm trying to get a single table of results showing the total number of pages printed grouped by the device serial number, then the department cost code and finally the user name.

The output would ideally look like this:

```
Device Serial   Cost Code  User Name      ColSpx   ColDpx   MonSpx   MonDpx   Price

CH238713498     2665473    Angela Rippon   43       22        245     566      £ 20
CH238713498     2665473    Warwick Davis    2        0       1000     230      £ 30
CH238713498     2623379    Carl Carlson    53        0       2145    1566      £ 55
CH238713498     2664443    Warwick Davis    2        0       1000     230      £ 30
```

The query I've been using (and changing without success) is:

```
DECLARE @ColourSimplex bigint SELECT TrackingPageCount
FROM TrackingTable    
WHERE JobIsColor = 1 AND JobIsDuplex = 0 AND JobType < 4 AND TrackingState = 2 AND (UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%SYSTEM%') AND TrackingPageCount > 0

DECLARE @ColourDuplex bigint SELECT TrackingPageCount
FROM TrackingTable
WHERE JobIsColor = 1 AND JobIsDuplex = 1 AND JobType < 4 AND TrackingState = 2 AND (UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%SYSTEM%') AND TrackingPageCount > 0

DECLARE @MonoSimplex bigint SELECT TrackingPageCount
FROM TrackingTable    
WHERE JobIsColor = 0 AND JobIsDuplex = 0 AND JobType < 4 AND TrackingState = 2 AND (UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%SYSTEM%') AND TrackingPageCount > 0

DECLARE @MonoDuplex bigint SELECT TrackingPageCount
FROM TrackingTable
WHERE JobIsColor = 0 AND JobIsDuplex = 1 AND JobType < 4 AND TrackingState = 2 AND (UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%SYSTEM%') AND TrackingPageCount > 0

SELECT  DeviceModel,
        UserCostCode,
        UserLogon,
        SUM(@ColourSimplex) AS 'Colour Simplex',
        SUM(@ColourDuplex) AS 'Colour Duplex',
        SUM(@MonoSimplex) AS 'Mono Simplex',
        SUM(@MonoDuplex) AS 'Mono Duplex',
        SUM(Price) AS 'Cost'

FROM TrackingTable

WHERE   StartDateTime BETWEEN '2017-05-31 23:59:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:00'

GROUP BY DeviceModel,
        UserCostCode,
        UserLogon

ORDER BY DeviceModel, UserCostCode, UserLogon
```

Here is an example of the results I'm getting:

```
L7L3Y01090  100951      MARINA SIRBU            NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.84
L7L3Y01090  A01016-DE06 MADELEINE MCALLISTER    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.168
L7L3Y01090  A02026-DE06 DANIEL POULTER          NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.448
```

Any help on how I can resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  DeviceModel,
        UserCostCode,
        UserLogon,
        SUM(CASE WHEN JobIsColor = 1 AND JobIsDuplex = 0 AND JobType < 4 AND TrackingState = 2 AND (UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%name%' AND UserLogon NOT LIKE '%SYSTEM%') AND TrackingPageCount > 0 THEN TrackingPageCount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'Colour Simplex',
        SUM(Price) AS 'Cost'

FROM TrackingTable

WHERE   StartDateTime BETWEEN '2017-05-31 23:59:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:00'

GROUP BY DeviceModel,
        UserCostCode,
        UserLogon

ORDER BY DeviceModel, UserCostCode, UserLogon
```

Add else column...

Comment: Amazing, I was barking up the wrong tree totally there.